# Can you revert back to using Username in DNN 7.3.4 module permission grid?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

In DNN 7.3.4 when adding a user individually to the module permissions grid you can only add them by the user's Display Name now.  This used to be done by Username.  It looks like it changed between DNN 7.0.2 and DNN 7.3.4.  This new way is useless if you have thousands of users and many of them have Display Names that are not unique. How are you to identify which John Smith you are looking for without the Username?  Please tell me there is a setting somewhere to change this back to Username but I have not been able to find one.  If so, please tell me where it is at or what I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would never recommend that you provide User based permissions for pages or modules. You should do everything with Roles.

Comment: @Weldon - Even if one person is in that role its 100% better than setting individuals up on pages as you are suggesting